# Drive missing after restart due to BSOD

Tags: hard-drive, windows-xp, bsod

My old XP computer got this BSOD

[image]

I have 3 IDE HDDs installed, `C`,`D`,`E`. After I restarted, `D` went missing from My Computer but it went back after another restart. I checked with CrystalDiskInfo but the health status is "good". It seems to work fine now but it might happen again, any idea on what is this  how to fix this?

Comment: I would suspect drive D is failing, they don't always show this in smart data. If it is an old PATA (IDE) hard drive try a new data cable.

Comment: **IdeChnDr.sys** is Intel Application Accelerator driver. Are you running the latest version of it ?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause would be that the drive D is failing on your computer, especially with the behaviour it has shown (simply disappearing after a BSOD), however it could also be to do with the *Intel Application Accelerator* being corrupt; you should uninstall it so Windows can use it's default IDE controller driver.